# Animation Nodes: cube root function

Tags: animation-nodes

I need to use the cube root function in animation nodes but there is no cube root in the math node.

Is there anyone who know how to do ?

Thank you

Comment: You should raise the number to the power of 1/3 or 0.3333333333333333 that will be 1/3 in 32bit float precision that numbers in Blender are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Power` function with `1/3` as exponent.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

If you know your way around python basics, you can also use an `Expression` node :

[image]